# get current state of check box jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap [iCheck](http://fronteed.com/iCheck/) plugin. How can i find out Whether a check box is checked or not by pressing a button using jquery

```
$(button).click(function(){

  ckb = $("#ickb").(isChecked);
});
```

Comment: Starting jquery 1.6 there have been significant changes the way attributes and properties are dealt with. For your case $('#ickb').prop("checked") should do the trick. This statement will simply return true or false depending upon the checked/unchecked state of the check box. For more details refer to attributes vs. properties section on [this](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) link.

Answer (score 73):

Try to use [`.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) function along with [`:checked`](http://api.jquery.com/checked/) selector to accomplish your task,

```
ckb = $("#ickb").is(':checked');
```

Answer (score 20):

Use [is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/) with [:checked](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) to get the result as boolean that is true if checkbox is checked.

```
ckb = $("#ickb").is(':checked');
```

Or, you can use length, if it is *zero* then it is not checked.

```
ckb = $("#ickb:checked").length
```

Comment: The second option is a single column

like so `$("#ickb:checked").length`

Your answer helped me