# Get checkbox selected state with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I tried many ways to get the selected state of a checkbox. Its a input field with type checkbox.

I tried the following methods to get the state, but all returns `false`. Only if the checkbox was set selected/not selected with jQuery before (this was done with `$.prop("checked", "true")`.

```
$("#ID").prop("checked");
$("#ID").val(); //returns "on" everytime
$("#ID").attr("checked");
$("#ID").checked; //undefined
```

ID is a real id in my Code!

The selected state is also set with jQuery like this:

```
$(columns[i]).children().first().prop("checked", stateArray[i]);
```

The checkboxes are in a KendoGrid and columns.children gets all `td`'s and `first()` returns the input.

`stateArray` is an array with true/false.

Nothing works... Do you got an idea?

Regards

EDIT: I found the fault... the ID generated for the inputs was always the same... so it selected the first element which was not selected... I'm sorry for that!

Comment: where is the object of element you need to target?

Comment: First select `checkbox` from `DOM` then read its `checked` property.

Comment: '<input id="ab3fee6b-c81e-e4ba-b12e-2c088bb386cc_A4" type="checkbox" data-role="check" otg-visible="true" style="-webkit-appearance: checkbox !important; width: 20px; height: 20px; display: table-cell; margin: 0px;">'

This is the object. I select it via JQuery with ID Selector

Comment: `.prop` and `.attr` should work.  Please show how you are actually using them.

Comment: 'var checkState = $("#" + target.id).prop("checked");                                 var id = equipmentDGM.getSelectedHiddenValue("hidden_id");
checkState = checkState == "true" ? "false" : "true";'

This is how i use the checkbox with an OnChange event. It always show "false"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [get current state of check box jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23911602/get-current-state-of-check-box-jquery)

Comment: These results also show "not selected" always...

Answer (score 2):

Where is your selector? Use `is(":checked")` with it like following.

```
var status = $(':checkbox').is(":checked");
```

Comment: Then use it like `$("#ID").is(":checked")` @szmast3r

Comment: dont work either :/ it returns false... Ill edit the start post and show how i set it selected or not selected... maybe that helps

Answer (score 1):

To find checkbox checked or not use `$('input[type="checkbox"]').prop("checked")`

For more understanding check below snippet.

```js
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change',function(){
  if($(this).prop('checked')){
    alert("checked");
  }else{
    alert("un-checked");  
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox"/>
```

Comment: Do i get a specific Element in a Grid? wont it return every input with type checkbox in my grid? 

I also need the selected row for a SQLQuery

Comment: Please my check my updated answer. If you have multiple checkbox then in that case you can use "on change" event listener of jquery and $(this) to get the status of checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

You need to select `checkbox` from `DOM` first then read its `checked` property.

```js
$(function() {
  console.log($('#ab3fee6b-c81e-e4ba-b12e-2c088bb386cc_A4').prop('checked'));
  console.log($('#ab3fee6b-c81e-e4ba-b12e-2c088bb386cc_A5').prop('checked'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="ab3fee6b-c81e-e4ba-b12e-2c088bb386cc_A4" type="checkbox" data-role="check" otg-visible="true" style="-webkit-appearance: checkbox !important; width: 20px; height: 20px; display: table-cell; margin: 0px;">
<input id="ab3fee6b-c81e-e4ba-b12e-2c088bb386cc_A5" type="checkbox" data-role="check" checked otg-visible="true" style="-webkit-appearance: checkbox !important; width: 20px; height: 20px; display: table-cell; margin: 0px;">
```

Comment: i tried this already... dont work :/ 

Changing the selected state with .prop("checked", "true/false") works... but not reading

Answer (score 0):

You could try either one of the followings:

```
$('#checkbox_id').is(":checked"); // jQuery

document.getElementById("checkbox_id").checked //JavaScript
```

return `true` if `checkbox` is checked